# Clicking on "edit" from the review queue doesn't warn about pending edit

Tags: bug, review-queues

Two weeks ago, I've noticed that clicking on *"edit"* from the review queue page when another edit is waiting for approval doesn't allow editing but doesn't warn the user about the pending edit.

[image]

Instead, doing the same thing from the page (not from the review queue), as expected, says:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Futher edits cannot
>   be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

[image]

I don't know if the problem is related to the browser, anyhow, I use *Google Chrome*.